# Is there a defect in the definition of the assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, variable-assignment

In my copy of the C++11 standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E)), the assignment operator definition includes:

> In simple assignment (`=`), the value of the expression replaces that of the object referred to by the left operand.

Shouldn't this say "value of the right operand" instead of "value of the expression"? At the moment it seems ambiguous and could easily be interpreted as meaning the "value of the assignment expression".

The phrase "the expression" is also used ambiguously in another paragraph of [expr.ass]:

> If the left operand is not of class type, the expression is implicitly converted (Clause 4) to the cv-unqualified type of the left operand

I think it means "right operand" here too, right?

This is also the only definition of the assignment operator's effects I can find. Am I missing something?

Comment: The value of the assignment expression *is* the value of the right-hand side...

Comment: That's §5.17/2 – what you're missing is the meaning of "expression" in this context, which is defined in §5.17/1.

Comment: @KerrekSB That would be circular logic because the value of the assignment expression is defined as "an lvalue referring to the left operand."

Comment: @ildjarn I don't see anything that defines the meaning of expression in this context. Am I going crazy here?

Comment: The left side is a lvalue not a value. So there is only one value in an assignment.

Answer (score 4):

The standard often assumes some **common sense** on the part of the reader.

For example, in places it apparently conflates the concepts of object and class.

This is done to avoid reducing readability via needless redundancies in the text, in keeping with the DRY principle: Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: Mixing _object_ and _class_ helps avoid repetition? Anyway, I think the main virtue of a language specification should be avoiding ambiguity, not avoiding repetition.

Comment: It's my common sense that tells me it's wrong. That's why I'm wondering if I'm missing something else (perhaps it is further defined elsewhere in the standard). If I'm not, then it's a defect - an international standard shouldn't be badly worded.

Comment: @jogojapan: Yes, e.g. when you discuss an "object and its member functions" instead of "an object of class type and the member functions of its most derived type". Formally of course objects do not have member functions.

Comment: @MSalters The proper way of handling a situation like this is to define abbreviations (e.g. "member functions of an object" as an abbreviation for the exact definition you gave) and then use these abbreviations. Using abbreviations or ambiguous terms without proper definition is neither necessary nor good practice.

Answer (score 3):

The "left operand" is correct in both cases:

1. The value being replaced is the object referred to by the left operand. It will get the value of the right operand but this isn't part of what the first quote describes.
2. When assigning a value to a non-class type the value is clearly converted to the type of the assigned to object, i.e., the left operand.

Comment: It's not "left operand" I have a problem with. It's "expression", when it seems like it should be "right operand".

Comment: @sftrabbit : The 'operand' is the thing being operated on; how could the RHS be an operand?

Comment: @ildjarn Both sides of the operator are operands of that operator, as used in the statement "the assignment is sequenced after the value
computation of the right and left operands".

Comment: ... also, the value of the [assignment] expression is what became the value of the left operand, replacing whatever value there was before.